# Distributing vertical space in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, whitespace

If I have a page in Word with several paragraphs, is it possible to automatically space them apart according to some proportions? For example, if the page is roughly:

```
pagebreak
paragraph
paragraph
paragraph
pagebreak
```

Can I put something after each paragraph that automatically takes up certain percents of the whitespace? For example:

```
pagebreak
paragraph
20% of whitespace
paragraph
50% of whitespace
paragraph
30% of whitespace
pagebreak
```

I know ways to manually adjust spacing until the percentages are just right. I'm wondering if I can just declare the percentages somehow (maybe using frames?). And even if, for example, one paragraph's text is edited to make it have more lines, the percentages on the white space will still hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with percentages. Take a look at vertical alignment - justified.
This is on the Layout Tab.

- Click on the Page Setup dialog launcher in the lower right corner of that group.
- This gives you the Page Layout dialog.
- You want the Layout tab in that dialog.
- In the center you will see Page - Vertical Alignment
- Choose Justified.

I do not know that this will give you what you want but it should be close.